# How to add toggle button on Razor Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How to add a toggle button on Razor Page with C#? I have tried to do it with common CSS commands, but it doesn't work.

[image: image here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

@section Scripts
{
    <style>
        .switch {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 60px;
            height: 34px;
        }

            .switch input {
                opacity: 0;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
            }

        .slider {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #ccc;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
        }

            .slider:before {
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                height: 26px;
                width: 26px;
                left: 4px;
                bottom: 4px;
                background-color: white;
                -webkit-transition: .4s;
                transition: .4s;
            }

        input:checked + .slider {
            background-color: #2196F3;
        }

        input:focus + .slider {
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }

        input:checked + .slider:before {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
            transform: translateX(26px);
        }

        .slider.round {
            border-radius: 34px;
        }

            .slider.round:before {
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
    </style>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thnx how to change it's value from database?  <input type="checkbox" checked="model => model.CompensationStatusForDriver">

Comment: and how to control it's size?